# Gradle Setting Manifest Class-Path on Jars in Ear

Tags: gradle, classpath, ear

### Set Up

I'm using Gradle and have a multi-project build using Java EE with IBM WebSphere Application Server. The project directory structure looks like this:

```
--/build.gradle
--/defaults.gradle
--/settings.gradle
--/common-ejb
--/common-ejb/build.gradle
--/logging
--/logging/build.gradle
--/project1
--/project1/build.gradle
--/project1-ejb
--/project1-ejb/build.gradle
--/project2
--/project2/build.gradle
--/project2-ejb
--/project2-ejb/build.gradle
```

`project1` and `project2` are individual ears that get deployed. They both reuse a number of EJBs from `common-ejb` and share some other library dependencies that aren't relevant for this question.

After performing the build: project1.ear looks like:

```
--/lib/log4j.jar
--/lib/logging.jar
--/META-INF/application.xml
--/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
--/common-ejb.jar
--/project1-ejb.jar
```

Gradle properly creates the application.xml to load EJBs from both projects. Unfortunately, `project1-ejb.jar` will fail to load due to dependencies on `common-ejb.jar`. The `project1-ejb.jar/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` needs to have the `Class-Path` set with `common-ejb.jar` since it's not in the `lib/` directory.

I was able to set it by explicitly defining it as done below. Gradle knows the dependencies for the `Class-Path`, so it should be able do this automatically. Is there a way to set this up?

### Gradle Files

Not including project2, but you can guess what it looks like.

--/build.gradle

```
apply from: 'defaults.gradle'
defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'
```

--/defaults.gradle

```
defaultTasks 'build'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

--/settings.gradle

```
include 'common-ejb'
include 'project1'
include 'project1-ejb'
include 'logging'
```

--/logging/build.gradle

```
apply from: '../defaults.gradle'

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'log4j:log4j:1.2.+'
}
```

--/common-ejb/build.gradle

```
apply from: '../defaults.gradle'

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'javax:javaee-api:6.0'

    compile project(':logging')
}
```

--/project1-ejb/build.gradle

```
apply from: '../defaults.gradle'

apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile 'javax:javaee-api:6.0'

    compile project(':common-ejb')
    compile project(':logging')
}
// THIS IS THE WORKAROUND, I don't want to explicitly modify the Class-Path for each EJB based on the EAR the EJB is going to be included in.
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Class-Path": project(':common-ejb').jar.archiveName)
    }
}
```

--/project1/build.gradle

```
apply from: '../defaults.gradle'

apply plugin: 'ear'
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    deploy project(':project1-ejb')
    deploy project(':common-ejb')

    earlib project(':logging')
}
```

Comment: Same question asked in http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/gradle_setting_manifest_class_path_on_jars_in_ear as well

Answer (score 0):

Using some information from and modifying code from [a question about getting all dependencies of a project](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/getting_all_project_dependencies) from the Gradle forums.

Essentially, you want to take the EAR's deploy dependencies and see if any deploy dependencies depend on each other. If they do, you set the Class-Path to include the referenced jars.

Remove the manifest lines from `project1-ejb` and `project2-ejb`. Add the following to your defaults.gradle:

```gradle
def getAllDependentProjects(project) {
    if ( !project.configurations.hasProperty("runtime") ) {
        return []
    }
    def projectDependencies = project.configurations.runtime.getAllDependencies().withType(ProjectDependency)
    def dependentProjects = projectDependencies*.dependencyProject
    if (dependentProjects.size > 0) { 
        dependentProjects.each { dependentProjects += getAllDependentProjects(it) }
    }
    return dependentProjects.unique()
}
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    if (plugins.hasPlugin('ear')) {
        def deployProjectDependencies = configurations.deploy.getAllDependencies().withType(ProjectDependency)*.dependencyProject
        deployProjectDependencies.each {
            def cur = it
            def cur_deps = getAllDependentProjects(cur)
            def depJars = []
            deployProjectDependencies.each {
                def search = it
                if ( cur_deps.contains(search)) {
                    depJars += search.jar.archiveName
                }
            }
            depJars = depJars.unique()
            if ( depJars.size() > 0 ) {
                logger.info("META-INF Dependencies for deploy dependency " + cur.name + ": " + depJars)
                cur.jar.manifest.attributes(
                    'Class-Path': depJars.join(' ')
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will have the desired affect. Directly after the configuration step and before build, the EAR projects will reevaluate their dependencies to see if any are cross-referenced. There may be a more efficient way, but this gets the job done.